# DStream.print() not outputting to console

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running  a simple HDFS stream Spark job which counts the words in text files located in a HDFS directory.

The code is taken from [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/HdfsWordCount.scala) example.

I notice that there is no output from the `wordCounts.print()` line, even though the log says that the new file was detected.

Looking at [the source for the function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L719), it seems I am definitely not getting output as the 'time' heading isn't bring printed either.

I am running on AWS EMR.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

```
./spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.rory.sparktest.WordCountStream --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 2G /home/hadoop/SparkStreamingTest2-1.0-bar.jar file:///home/hadoop/streamtest/
```

Comment: Which command do want me to execute?

Comment: Is your issue resolved. I am also facing this issue